# RMMapView setCenterCoordinate function is not normally

Tags: iphone, ios, mapbox

I want to set center of RMMapView with position that's _tempCoordinated2D (CLLocationCoordinate2D)

Normally, It should be

```
// _rmMapView is RMMapView Class

[_rmMapView setCenterCoordinate:_tempCoordinated2D];

// I try [_rmMapView setCenterCoordinate:_tempCoordinated2D animated:YES];
// I try [_rmMapView setCenterCoordinate:_tempCoordinated2D animated:NO];
```

Result's wrong.

Because Center of the rmMapView move to _tempCoordinated2D and move back to Current Location.
I have checked my code. It doesn't have a code that's setCenterCoordinate to Current Location.

**The problem is not just that.**
BUT This's a problem hasn't occurred , 
If I touch the map and move map before run statement setCenterCoordinate of RMMapView.

I don't know why.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `userTrackingMode` set on the `RMMapView` that is causing it to center on the user? Try setting that to `RMUserTrackingModeNone`.